# How can i insert a .bin created on desktop file into apk

Tags: android, file, android-studio

I have code for creating an internal file, there is random algorithem that create the data stored in it and i want any app to have the same file with the same binary data in it.

so i need to make the file on my desktop and add it to internal files some how.

my question is what do you think is the best way to do it. 
i thought to locate it in my project, read it, and write it to internal files.

the problem is, i dont know where to locate my file in android studio so that it will be included in the external files and then where to read it from.

thanks. =]
hope i made myself clear.

Comment: I think assets/raw/ will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in `src/main/assets/`.

You can then access your file with [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) and do whatever you want with it.

From the [Android Developers website](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationModules):

> `main/assets/`
>
> This is empty. You can use it to store raw asset files. Files that you
>   save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the original
>   filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the same way
>   as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of
>   bytes using the [`AssetManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html). For example, this is a good location for
>   textures and game data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move that into the assets folder. From there you can refer to the file.